# Need help understanding lowByte and highByte

Tags: c++, byte, uint8t

I'm a beginner with C++ and I'd like to decipher some code:

```
    #define lowByte(w) ((uint8_t) ((w) & 0xff))
    #define highByte(w) ((uint8_t) ((w) >> 8))
```

It looks like variable declaration but I've never seen this syntax before. Can someone break these two lines down and tell me what they mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html) declarations.

Whenever you have `lowByte(0x1234)` in your code, it will be replaced with the right part of the macro, substituting arguments with their values, that is `((uint8_t) ((0x1234) & 0xff))`.

This step is performed by the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) prior to compilation.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain what ((uint8_t)  ((0x1234) & (0xff)) means?

Comment: It's a [bitwise AND operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) between the hexadecimal numbers `0x1234` and `0xFF`, which yields the result `0x34`. The result is then cast to the `uint8_t` type.